# How to use "IN" operator from SQL for writing LDAP query

Tags: sql, ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I want to use "IN" operator from SQL for writing LDAP query.

For ex: If I have a list of names called "NameList", I write the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE NAME IN "NameList"
```

How do I do write similar LDAP Query?

```
public static final String[] LDAP_ATTRIBUTE_IDS = {"displayName"};

LdapContext ldapContext = new InitialLdapContext(env, null); \\env has all 
 \\connection details

List NameList = new ArrayList<String>();
NameList.add("ABC");
NameList.add("XYZ");
NameList.add("LMN");

NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration = ldapContext.search("",
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(|(sAMAccountName=XYZ)(sAMAccountName=LMN)(sAMAccountName=ABC)))", getSearchControls());

Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) namingEnumeration.next()).getAttributes();
String value = attrs.get(LDAP_ATTRIBUTE_IDS);
```

Instead on adding XYZ,LMN and ABC using "|" operator I would Like to know if NameList can be used with "IN" operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent `IN` operator for searching LDAP.

Maybe you're not using Active Directory, but AD does support an [SQL Dialect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/win32/adsi/sql-dialect) for searching, but even then, it doesn't support `IN`.

So the only way to do this is the way you already are. If you have your `NameList` array, you can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to build the query. Something like this:

```
NamingEnumeration namingEnumeration = ldapContext.search("",
"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(|(sAMAccountName=" + String.join(")(sAMAccountName=", NameList) + ")))", getSearchControls());
```